# Electron beam can damange a material surface?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons

When an electron beam hits the surface of a material (i.e aluminum) does this damage the surface of the material? does this depend on the surface of incidence of the material and the current per second that hits the surface? is there an equation to calculate this?

Comment: Given you can melt the material (electron beam welding is a common thing), yes you can damage it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron-beam_welding and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron-beam_additive_manufacturing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one directs an electron beam onto an object like a piece of metal a current passes through said body.

According to Ohm’s law the power dissipated by the corresponding current is:

$$P = R I^2$$

Where I is the intensity of the current a R the resistance of the object.

If I is a large value, then the amount of energy transferred to the object can be high and it temperature can be elevated.

So basically, if the resulting temperature associated with the transfer of energy is moderate (iron, radiator, resistor in a radio) the object will just heat up.

If the current (beam) has a high enough intensity the object might melt under the heat (electric welding, object hit by lightning, etc.)

An other consequence of an object being hit by a beam of electrons is:

To accelerate electrons towards a metallic target, one has to apply a given voltage that will allow the electrons to cross a given air gap, typically a few thousands volts for a spark plug, for instance. However when said electrons hit the target they are abruptly decelerated. Charged particles which are accelerated / decelerated emit radiation (their kinetic energy turns into photons). That’s how X-ray generators work. The X-ray themselves could have an effect on the object if they have a large enough intensity (affect the cristalline lattice of the oject).